# Need help to identify this diode

Tags: diodes, identification, zener

Need help identifying this SMD component which is shorted.  I suspect it is a Zener diode. I have searched the markings ad nauseam but could not find an answer.

The length is 5mm, so I believe it is a SMA package

Markings are:
LT7B27
HE

Any hints are greatly appreciated, thanks!

[image: LT7B27 HE diode]

Comment: This TVS diode [SM6T22A](https://www.vishay.com/docs/88385/sm6t.pdf) indicates part marking of LT7. Not sure if the dimensions quite match though.

Comment: As suggested by @gcr I purchased a [SM6T22A](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/stmicroelectronics/sm6t22a/?qs=gr8Zi5OG3MjD1P3f%2F2mN%252bw%3D%3D&countrycode=US&currencycode=USD) and the unit is 100% working now. Thank you!